# Spree api key in version 1.1.0.rc2

Tags: spree

I have generated a spree website with the version **1.1.0.rc2** , now I am unable to find the generate api key option as available in the previous versions of spree under the users tag.

I need to generate the api key for the integration of spree with OpenERP module esale_spree developed by ting.

note: esale_spree is a connector module for OpenERP and spree site.

Q. Have they removed the generate api key option from the users tag ?
Q. Which is the last spree version which supported this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. The button was missing from the 1.1 release. The following code in your console will generate an API key.

```
Spree::User.find_by_email("spree@example.com").generate_api_key!
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found following to work for me

```
Spree::User.find_by_email("spree@example.com").spree_generate_api_key!
```

Answer (score 0):

When I accessed this through the console, I actually found that this was what worked for me

`Spree::User.find_by_email("spree@example.com").generate_spree_api_key!`

I found it by looking through the spree documentation in this page in the section: "#generate_api_key ⇒ Object"

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/spree_backend/2.4.2/Spree/Admin/UsersController

```
# File 'app/controllers/spree/admin/users_controller.rb', line 82

def generate_api_key
    if @user.generate_spree_api_key!
       flash[:success] = Spree.t('api.key_generated')
    end
    redirect_to edit_admin_user_path(@user)
end
```